# ChainCode container lifecycle clarification

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

So i would like to know whether my setup has some flaws or i didn't get the concept of chaincode container lifecycle.

The issue is the following. After installing/instantiating chaincode on a channel i have to make a query/invoke via the docker cli to the chaincode before i'm able to do the same from nodejs backend with the corresponding enrolled peer.

So when watching docker logs the chaincode container is not live until i made the call from docker cli. Is this intended? Or did miss something to set up? Would be very cool to clarify this issue for me or post some documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, Why this happens is because the fabric on instantiation only spins up a docker container of chaincode only on the peer that instantiated it. So, when you're trying to invoke or query chaincode through some other peer, it needs to first bring up the container then will do the queries.

An alternative is to instantiate the chaincode through all endorsing peers in channel as targets.This ensures that all the peers in the channel has the container before the invoke or query.

If you're using go-sdk this is done through `withTargets() or withTargetEndpoints()`:

```
peers = ["peer1.org1.example.com","peer1.org2.example.com"]
req := InstantiateCCRequest{Name: "name", Version: "version", Path: "path", Policy: ccPolicy}
, err := rc.InstantiateCC("mychannel", req, WithTargets(peers...))
```

Similar logic is used in cli call, a man to chaincode instantiate gives (Look for `NOTICE --->` where I've marked the required flag):

````
Deploy the specified chaincode to the network.

Usage:
  peer chaincode instantiate [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --collections-config string      The fully qualified path to the collection JSON file including the file name
      --connectionProfile string       Connection profile that provides the necessary connection information for the network. Note: currently only supported for providing peer connection information
  -c, --ctor string                    Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -E, --escc string                    The name of the endorsement system chaincode to be used for this chaincode
  -h, --help                           help for instantiate
  -l, --lang string                    Language the chaincode is written in (default "golang")
  -n, --name string                    Name of the chaincode
"NOTICE--->"   --peerAddresses stringArray      The addresses of the peers to connect to
  -P, --policy string                  The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode
      --tlsRootCertFiles stringArray   If TLS is enabled, the paths to the TLS root cert files of the peers to connect to. The order and number of certs specified should match the --peerAddresses flag
  -v, --version string                 Version of the chaincode specified in install/instantiate/upgrade commands
  -V, --vscc string                    The name of the verification system chaincode to be used for this chaincode

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --connTimeout duration                Timeout for client to connect (default 3s)
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding```
````